# PYTHON. Label values contained in single column dataset according to second dataset with ranges and labels

Tags: python, sorting, label

I have a dataset with column named "Value" to which i want to add a second column "Name" based on the information of a second dataset with two columns "Label" and "Start".

Have to check where each number in the "Value" column falls in the "Start" column and return the corresponding value from "Label".

For example: Value = 50 is between 0 and 100 from "Start" column. Have to return "Label" A.

Thank you.

[Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IBCFa.png)

Comment: Can name's repeat again in higher range ? like value could be **500** & Name is **A**

Answer (score 0):

Using [pandas.cut()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.cut.html#pandas-cut)

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Label': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'], 'start': [0, 100, 150, 250, 300]})

df = pd.DataFrame({'value': [0, 50, 75, 100, 150,200, 220, 250, 275, 300, 400]})

bins = np.append(df2.start, [np.inf])
df['Name'] = pd.cut(df.value, bins, labels=df2.Label, right=False)
```

**Output:**

```
    value Name
0       0    A
1      50    A
2      75    A
3     100    B
4     150    C
5     200    C
6     220    C
7     250    D
8     275    D
9     300    E
10    400    E
```

Comment: Thank you very much!!!. Haven't used the pd.cut before. Seems to do the job!!!

Comment: One question, what is the purpose of np.inf as an argument in np.append? THanks again.

Comment: bins should have one value greater than labels